# How can i show only US tv-shows in my film project?

Tags: javascript

I have created a film project using the MovieDB API. While the movie section is functioning properly, the TV shows section seems to predominantly display Indian TV shows. I want display only US tv Shows. Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Code:

```
async function displayPopularShows() {
  const { results } = await fetchAPIData('/tv/popular');

  results.forEach((show) => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('card');
    div.innerHTML = `
          <a href="tv-details.html?id=${show.id}">
            ${
              show.poster_path
                ? `<img
              src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${show.poster_path}"
              class="card-img-top"
              alt="${show.name}"
            />`
                : `<img
            src="../images/no-image.jpg"
            class="card-img-top"
            alt="${show.name}"           
          />`
            }
          </a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">${show.name}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">
              <small class="text-muted">Air Date: ${show.first_air_date}</small>
            </p>
          </div>
        `;

    document.querySelector('#popular-shows').appendChild(div);
  });
}
```

I want display only US tv Shows.

Comment: That totally depends on the API. If they have the ability for you to specify what it gives you back, or a way to filter what you get back by some kind of category. That's the only way to do it since the code can't just tell what the TV show type is

Comment: use filter function. `rows.filter((row) => {row.country === 'USA'})`. Also just a suggestion, you would be better off using a library like `React` for easily creating web applications rather than using div.innerHTML. It's just a suggestion, don't take it seriously.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`watch-region`](https://developer.themoviedb.org/reference/discover-tv#query-discoverTv_watch_region) parameter

to make the request look something like

`await fetchAPIData('/tv/popular?watch_region=US');`

If that does not work (since it is not in the popular URL documentation page), then you can use the generic TV and add sort by popularity and watch-region

`/tv?include_adult=false&include_null_first_air_dates=false&language=en-US&page=1&sort_by=popularity.desc&watch_region=US`